# Error creating a proxy class from a WSDL. Element missing?

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl

I will admit I am ignorant when it comes to WSDLs.  I was provided the following WSDL for a project I am working on, but it isn't working. Here is a post of the WSDL I am using. I was asked to remove the actual URL to the service from the wsdl so that it didn't get indexed and hit by crawlers.  The actual URL has been replaced with 'www.testsite.org'.  Here is the XML:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="https://www.testsite.org/uiws-test" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="uiicon" targetNamespace="https://www.testsite.org/uiws-test">
<!-- TYPES -->
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.testsite.org/uiws-test">
<xsd:complexType name="ResponseType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="request_id" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="messages" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="responseType" type="tns:ResponseType"/>
<xsd:element name="ICON_MessageTrain" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="fault" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<!-- MESSAGES -->
<wsdl:message name="RequestMessage">
<wsdl:part name="ICON_MessageTrain" element="tns:ICON_MessageTrain"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ResponseMessage">
<wsdl:part name="response" element="tns:responseType"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="FaultMessage">
<wsdl:part name="fault" element="tns:fault"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SourceHeader">
<wsdl:part name="source" element="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ApplicationHeader">
<wsdl:part name="application" element="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<!-- PORT TYPES -->
<wsdl:portType name="uiicon_portType">
<wsdl:operation name="uiicon">
<wsdl:input message="tns:RequestMessage"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ResponseMessage"/>
<wsdl:fault message="tns:FaultMessage" name="FaultMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<!-- BINDINGS -->
<wsdl:binding name="uiicon_binding" type="tns:uiicon_portType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="uiicon">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://www.testsite.org/uiws-test/services/uiicon-test" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:header part="source" message="tns:SourceHeader" use="literal"/>
<soap:header part="application" message="tns:ApplicationHeader" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="FaultMessage">
<soap:fault name="FaultMessage" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<!-- SERVICES -->
<wsdl:service name="uiicon_service">
<wsdl:documentation>
This is the web service for UI-ICON data exchange modernization project
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:port name="uiicon_port" binding="tns:uiicon_binding">
<soap:address location="https://www.testsite.org/uiws-test/services/uiicon-test"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I run this in wsdl.exe, I get the following error:

- Unable to import operation 'uiicon'.
- The element 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string' is missing

I see where the wsdl is referencing the w3.org 2001 schema, and I see the string schema reference.  Just not sure what it should look like and why it is wrong.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WSDL is valid if you change `element` to `type` in your `SourceHeader` and `ApplicationHeader` references, i.e.:

```
<wsdl:message name="ApplicationHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="application" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SourceHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="source" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

With `element` you reference a predefined simple or complex type. Here, however you define a new element (called application/source) that is of type `xsd:string`. Therefore, you need to use `type`.

As far as I see, you simply want a single message part called application that contains a string. The fix should make this work and the WSDL is valid. I can't guarantee what the actual Web Service will accept/send, given its description is invalid, though...

Comment: Thank you!  I sent this info back to the service provider, and an update has been made that seems to be working.

Comment: Good to hear, I'm glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is as cut-and-dry as the accepted answer makes it out to be.

Based on my reading of the [WSDL 1.1 spec, section 2.3.1 Message Parts](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_message), this WSDL should be valid.

It is also my understanding that one of the key items to determine whether you should use element or type is based on the binding style - rpc vs. document, literal vs. encoded. [An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1173153/27088) goes into more detail, as does the [article that the answer  references](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/).

As this WSDL does use a document/literal binding, it seems to me that use of element over type is correct.